# Join match with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables in which join doubles the count as condition matches twice in second table.
One is the Events table that captures senderId, receiverId, statusId and bulkId. Another table is Phones table which captures userId and phoneNumber. A user can have multiple phones so there can be multiple entries for a user in Phones table.

I write a query something like:-

```
SELECT 
    receiverId,
    senderId,
    ph.number,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN e.statusId IN (40 , 41) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS failed,
    COUNT(e.statusId) AS total
FROM
    Events e
        JOIN
    Phones ph ON ph.userId = e.senderId
WHERE
    e.bulkId = 3;
```

Unfortunately above query multiplies `failed` and `total` with Phone numbers count but i want that to avoid.

Comment: Firstly aggregate and count/sum (in subquery), then join.

Comment: Your query is missing a `group by` clause. What are you really trying to do? Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Edit your question and provide table aliases, so it is clear where the columns come from.  Provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you mean by "join doubles".